# DataGridView to text file on Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, streamwriter

I have a datagridview that I want to write to a text file. Here is my code:

```
private void WriteToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter("list.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        string lines = "";
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
        {
            lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines) ? " " : ", ") + 
                dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
        }
        sW.WriteLine(lines);
        sW.Close();
    }
}
```

and when I click the button it gives me an error:

> System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Hi Joe, try putting a little more effort in your question. For example, when you debug through the WriteToFile_Click, where does it return a null reference?

Details like this help us, help you.

Comment: Check if your grid isn't smaller then 6x6

Comment: Oh im sorry, it return a null reference on lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines) ? " " : ", ") + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value.ToString();

Comment: How do I check it @wdc

Comment: `DataGridView.ColumnCount`and
`DataGridView.RowCount`

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Your cell has no value, so trying to call ToString() on it won't work.  Always save to a full path, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Joe,

Try using a for each for your loops:

```
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter("list.txt");
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView.Rows) {
    string lines = "";
    foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells) {
        lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines) ? " " : ", ") + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value;
    }

    sW.WriteLine(lines);
}
```

Comment: Looks better for sure, but you do need to check for null on c.Value before doing ToString() otherwise you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

one or more values in your grid are `null`, or, to put it in other words, 'nothing'. So, when you're using accessing `dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value` property, and then converting it to string, you're trying to covertz `null` to string which then throws exception.
You should check for null values, something like this:

(if you're using .net 4.6)

```
lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines) ? " " : ", ") + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value?.ToString();
```

notice the extra question mark after `Value`

(if you're using older .net)

```
lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines) ? " " : ", ") + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value;
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Since you're getting `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, make sure you're not getting out of grid's bounds - trying to access a row or column to many. To be sure you're in the bound, use

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
```

for your first loop and

```
for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView.ColumnCount; col++)
```

for second

Comment: I get this when I try the code
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred